# Rails simple_form parameters not working in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, simple-form

I have two models:

```
class TransferRoute < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transfers
end

class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :transfer_route
end
```

Each `TransferRoute` has a return_route_id corresponding with the return route.

I use `simple_form` to add a new transfer and is working. In the controller I want to create another `Transfer` for which I will change some fields inside (I will create return transfer, switch departure with destination).

What I have in `transfers_controller` :

```
transfer_route = TransferRoute.find(params['transfer[transfer_route_id]'])
transfer_route_2 = TransferRoute.find(tr.return_route_id)
```

I get the following error:

`Couldn't find TransferRoute without an ID`

If I use transfer_route = TransferRoute.find(1) is working.

Is something wrong with the params?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also show how and where you define "tr"?

Comment: It's a typo, it should be transfer_route. I renamed some variables to make it more readable. The error I get is one line up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your params call is not correctly, you get nil as return. Params is the hash, you must call the key from params:

```
params[:transfer][:transfer_route_id]
```

full code:

```
transfer_route = TransferRoute.find(params[:transfer][:transfer_route_id])
```